# I am unable to click the Check box in a table when cell has more fields

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Problem in check checkbox for this table http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55228056/Locators.html
Under complex table you can see check box under Access,I would like to check those check boxes using java in Selenium.

Below is the code which i tried ..

I have created a class for a Web table

```
public class Table 
{
public WebElement getCellEditor(int rowIdx,int colIdx,int editorIdx)
{
    try
    {
    List<WebElement> tablerows=_webTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    WebElement currentrow=tablerows.get(rowIdx-1);
    List<WebElement> tablecols=currentrow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    WebElement cell=tablecols.get(colIdx-1);
    WebElement cellEditor=cell.findElements(By.tagName("input")).get(editorIdx);

    return cellEditor;

    }catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {

        throw new NoSuchElementException("Failed to get cell editor");
    }

    }
```

extended same to other class.

```
public class TestWebTable 
{

public void printTable() throws InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
        Table table=new Table(driver.findElement(By.id("users")));
        WebElement cellEdit=table.getCellEditor(3,3 ,2);
        cellEdit.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        /*WebElement cellEdit2=table.getCellEditor(3,3,4);
        cellEdit2.click();*/


    }catch(Error e)
    {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
        System.out.println(verificationErrors.toString());
    }
}
```

If I execute above to check the check box by giving (3,3 ,2) to (rowindex,columnindex,editorindex) the check box wont get checked.

Comment: all sorts of things could be wrong here... in general your code looks ok though. are you sure you set the ```_webTable``` in your Table class? What happens in your program. did you run it in a debugger yet?

Comment: What exceptions, if any, are you seeing when you try to complete the click?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, then the table has only 2 rows. So the indexes of the rows list should be 0 and 1. You are trying to get the row with index 2 (rowIdx-1) which does not exist in the list of tablerows.
Could you try printing the size of each list as you create it ?